# How to modify two arrays on a model using $pull mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, pull

I have a user model and on that user model there are two arrays filled with userIds (following, and followed_by). I am looking to remove the same value from both of those two arrays (if it exists) and am wondering if I can use $pull to modify two separate arrays. Or if there is another way I should go about removing this value.
I'm just not sure of the right syntax, as it works fine just using pull with one array.

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
   {_id: userId}, 
   {$pull: {followed_by: blockedUserId},
            {following : blockedUserId}},
   {new: true}
)
.then(user => {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is an issue with the syntax. It should be

`{ $pull: { <field1>: <value|condition>, <field2>: <value|condition>, ... } }`

So in your case, you can try something like

```js
{$pull: { followed_by: blockedUserId, following: blockedUserId }}
```